# Generar un Beep continuo como el de las señales horarias de la radio para windows forms c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo una pregunta respondida en la que preguntaba como crear un reloj para reproducir las señales horarias como las de la radio, en que al llegar la hora, suena un:

Beep, Beep, Beep, Beep, Beep, Beeeeeeeeeeeep

El reloj ya lo he podido crear gracias a la respuesta de @el.trasgu

Pero me sigue quedando pendiente generar el Beep largo y continuo con el mismo tono que el resto

hasta ahora, a parte del código para generar el reloj, tengo:

```
private void lblReloj_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:54")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:55")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:56")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:57")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:58")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:59")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:00")
    {
        Console.Beep(20000, 800);
    }
}
```

No se si funciona, si lo hace, la idea, sería que al llegar el reloj a los segundos "00", hicieses el Beep largo

Alguien me podría decir como reproducirlo ?   Gracias

Vaya, pues no me ha funcionado. Alguna idea de como poder comparar el valor del label ?

He utilizado:

```
    if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:54")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:59:54")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    if (lblReloj.Text == "hh:mm:54")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    if (lblReloj.Text == "??:??:54")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    if (lblReloj.Text == "*54")
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me he picado por solucionar el problema que se te ha presentado, además que me parece un método interesante para darle funcionalidad a una aplicación, así que me he puesto a investigar.

He dado con la solución para que se reproduzca el Beep, lo que no logrado es reproducir en la misma frecuencia del Beep por defecto, aquí ya sería cuestión de ir probando hasta llegar a conseguirlo

te pongo el código completo de como quedaría:

Load del formulario:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Ponemos el cambio cada segundo.  
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);

        // Iniciamos el reloj
        timer.Start();

        btnReloj.Text = "Stop";
        btnReloj.Click += new EventHandler(btnReloj_Click);
    }
```

Método Timer del timer incrustado en el formulario:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Capturamos la hora y la escribimos en el TextBox.  
        lblReloj.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
        //He creado nuevos Label, donde capturo las horas, los minutos y los segundos de forma individualizada. Estos están ocultos, podrías dejarlos visibles con la propiedad visible a true.
        lblHoras.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh");
        lblHoras.Visible = false;
        lblMinutos.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm");
        lblMinutos.Visible = false;
        lblSegundos.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("ss");
        lblSegundos.Visible = false;
        lblFecha.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();

        if ((lblMinutos.Text == "59") && (lblSegundos.Text == "54"))
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if ((lblMinutos.Text == "59") && (lblSegundos.Text == "55"))
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if ((lblMinutos.Text == "59") && (lblSegundos.Text == "56"))
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if ((lblMinutos.Text == "59") && (lblSegundos.Text == "57"))
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if ((lblMinutos.Text == "59") && (lblSegundos.Text == "58"))
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if ((lblMinutos.Text == "59") && (lblSegundos.Text == "59"))
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
        if ((lblMinutos.Text == "59") && (lblSegundos.Text == "00"))
        {
            //no he conseguido reproducir la misma frecuencia del sonido por defecto del Beep, sería cuestión de probar
            Console.Beep(800, 1500);
        }
    }
```

Método del Botón que inicia y detiene el reloj a la vez que sustituye el texto del mismo

```
private void btnReloj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnReloj.Text == "Stop")
        {
            btnReloj.Text = "Start";
            timer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            btnReloj.Text = "Stop";
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

EDITADO

pues conseguido, la frecuencia es de 800, el tiempo de duración del Beep lo he puesto en 1500 milisegundos

He corregido también el código para que solo se reproduzca el sonido con cada hora, y no con cada minuto

Espero sea lo que buscas, un saludo

Comment: Pues muchísimas gracias @el.trasgu, es exactamente lo que buscaba, me has alegrado el día. ers un fenómeno, gracias de verdad.